# delete icons shows up as question mark on Swipe Row

Tags: react-native

I am using Swipe Row from @nghinv/react-native-swipe-row
where there is an option to delete the item from the list when it is swiped to the left. The label shows up correctly but the delete icon has an issue as it shows a question mark where the icon name is correct. What is the possible reason for this? how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Usually it's better to ask in library's issues - https://github.com/nghinv-software/react-native-swipe-row/issues, and/or provide here your code